# Package and execute jar file from react-native app

Tags: jar, react-native

I have a jar library which I want to be able to use from my react-native app. Currently I'm working on an android project and I want to be able to execute the jar from based on some user interactions. Is this possible and if it is, how can I do this? Bonus points if it's possible for iOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

To use a jar library within a react-native app, you can follow these steps:

1. Copy the jar file somewhere inside android folder
2. Declare the jar file as a dependency of the android app project

```
compile files('<path_to_jar_file>.jar')
```

3. Create a native module (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android), call to your jar file classes inside the java code and expose the functionalities via javascript module

You can also make a library from that jar file and your native module code (https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library)
Unfortunately, you cannot directly use the jar file for ios.
You can find a similar library for ios and create the ios native module and expose the same interface so your js module is cross-platform.